# why does adding an index on something you sort by decrease the amount of work in sorting?

Tags: mysql, sql

From here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

`In some cases, MySQL can use an index to satisfy an ORDER BY clause without doing any extra sorting.`

I thought indexes helped with retrieving specific pieces of data (like the indexes in array) giving you a O(1) instead of O(n) when indexed. But when sorting, I assumed they use whatever O(nlogn) or something algorithm based on the sorting column, however apparently indexing the columns you sort by can decrease the amount of work involve.

How does this work? ( I am not sure if this is a general SQL thing or a MySQL thing either )

Comment: It's general, not specific to mysql.

Comment: Think about an index of a book - if you are looking for a term, do you need to look through the whole book or the sorted index in order to find what page it is on?

Comment: @Oded: I am familiar with how it works when looking for a specific item -- I am unsure how it works when sorting a list of items, indexed or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple answer: Generally, indexes are themselves stored in sorted order (otherwise, using an index to quickly find a record would be extremely difficult!) Hence, "in some cases" (when an ORDER BY matches the sort order of an index), the data can be returned via its index order, "without doing any extra sorting".

Further: As @Will A's answer reminded me, you may wish to learn about [covering indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29#Covering_Index), which extend this concept.

Answer (score 3):

Performing a lookup of a single row in an index is likely an O(log n) operation or thereabouts.

When reading through an index in 'sort order', however, you're typically performing a tree- or even list- traversal, and this'll be O(n).  If the index contains all of the information needed to satisfy the output of the query, this'll be considerably faster than reading and sorting the data.

This is a general SQL thing, not specific to MySQL.

Comment: +1 Good point about an index containing all information needed to satisfy the query. This is why [covering indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29#Covering_Index) can be useful on commonly-queried data.